# Same div ID on page to collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two `div` on same page with same id. I want explore description of one `div`. In my case if i click on div then all `desc` are expand.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var collapsed = "image";

  $("#shw_desc").click(function() {
    if ($(".desc").is(":visible")) {
      $(".desc").slideUp();
      $("#shw_desc_icon img").attr("src", collapsed).css("transform", "rotate(0deg)");
    } else {
      $(".desc").slideDown();
      $("#shw_desc_icon img").attr("src", collapsed).css("transform", "rotate(180deg)");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shw_desc" style="background-color: #dfdfdf;font-size: 14px;float: left;padding: 4px 12px;width: 90.3%;color: #666;" class="nt_selected">
  <span>Description</span><span id="shw_desc_icon" style="float:right;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"><img class="block-hider-hide" alt="Hide Administration block" src="image" tabindex="0" title="Hide Administration block"></span>
</div>
<div class="desc" style="display:none;border: 1px solid #eee;padding: 6px 12px;color: #999;font-size: 13px;width:90%;float: left;">
  <p>Some Description</p>
</div>

<div id="shw_desc" style="background-color: #dfdfdf;font-size: 14px;float: left;padding: 4px 12px;width: 90.3%;color: #666;" class="nt_selected">
  <span>Description 2</span><span id="shw_desc_icon" style="float:right;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"><img class="block-hider-hide" alt="Hide Administration block" src="image" tabindex="0" title="Hide Administration block"></span>
</div>
<div class="desc" style="display:none;border: 1px solid #eee;padding: 6px 12px;color: #999;font-size: 13px;width:90%;float: left;">
  <p>Some Description 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't have two div's with the same id, id's are supposed to be unique

Comment: `I have two div on same page with same id` This is invalid in HTML. `id` attributes must be unique within a page. Change the markup to use a common `class` attribute on those elements instead

Comment: using same id more than once on single page is not a good approach. Even you can write same ids but when you are going to bind an event, it will always bind to first element at the time of parsing. You can use class instead and pick `:first` selector

Comment: Hi Dibsy Jr, Thanks but I dont have access to change div ID. I know it is possible through jquery. I am trying it but not found it yet.

Comment: If you can not access div id, you should write code to first remove all ids which are same with a class. Then pick selector which I've told above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have two div on same page with same id

This is invalid in HTML. id attributes must be unique within a page. Change the markup to use a common class attribute on those elements instead.

From there you can use the `this` keyword to reference the element that raised the `click` event and find the related elements which should be amended.

Also note that you can simplify the logic in your JS code by using `slideToggle()` and `toggleClass()` over an `if` statement, and you can simplify the HTML by putting the inline styles in to a stylesheet. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var collapsed = "image";

  $(".shw_desc").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open').next('.desc').slideToggle();
    $(this).find(".shw_desc_icon img").attr("src", collapsed);
  });
});
```

```css
.shw_desc {
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: left;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  width: 90.3%;
  color: #666
}
.shw_desc_icon {
  float: right;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.shw_desc.open .shw_desc_icon {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.desc {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 90%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shw_desc nt_selected">
  <span>Description 1</span>
  <span class="shw_desc_icon glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right">
    <img class="block-hider-hide" alt="Hide Administration block" src="image" tabindex="0" title="Hide Administration block">
  </span>
</div>
<div class="desc">
  <p>Some Description 1</p>
</div>
<div class="shw_desc nt_selected">
  <span>Description 2</span>
  <span class="shw_desc_icon glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right">
    <img class="block-hider-hide" alt="Hide Administration block" src="image" tabindex="0" title="Hide Administration block">
  </span>
</div>
<div class="desc">
  <p>Some Description 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rory, It worked for me but i would like to go with Fran's Answer. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers should be unique and is considered invalid Html.

I recommend to ensure to use either a class or data attribute to select your elements and what ever generates the Html ensures unique identifiers are used,..or leave them out all together if not needed.

> **However**, assuming you might not be able to change the generated HTML I will be using your exact markup and only apply the least amount
>   of changes in the script to make it work.

For the `click` event you can use `[id=identifier]` instead of `#identifier` in your selector, like this `$("[id=shw_desc]").click(function() {`

This works as selecting by attribute can return multiple results, however, when selecting by identifier `$(#...)` jQuery will only return the first match.

Within the click event handler code, make sure you always stay within the current context.
This applies, regardless what selector you are using to bind the `click` handler.

If a `shw_desc` has been clicked, you don't want to process all `.desc` elements but only the one next to the current `shw_desc` that was clicked.

Same for `#shw_desc_icon img`, you only want to process the image located within the `shw_desc` that was clicked and not all the others on the page. For this you can use a selector similar to `$("#shw_desc_icon img", this)`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var collapsed = "image";

  // Select by attribute to bind to ALL shw_desc elements not just the first one
  $("[id=shw_desc]").click(function() {
    var $desc = $(this).next('.desc'); //Get the .desc element next to the current context.
    
    if ($desc.is(":visible")) {
      $desc.slideUp();
      
      // Use ',this' to ensure you only query for #shw_desc_icon within the current context.
      $("#shw_desc_icon img", this).attr("src", collapsed).css("transform", "rotate(0deg)");
    } else {
      $desc.slideDown();
      $("#shw_desc_icon img", this).attr("src", collapsed).css("transform", "rotate(180deg)");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shw_desc" style="background-color: #dfdfdf;font-size: 14px;float: left;padding: 4px 12px;width: 90.3%;color: #666;" class="nt_selected">
  <span>Description</span><span id="shw_desc_icon" style="float:right;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"><img class="block-hider-hide" alt="Hide Administration block" src="image" tabindex="0" title="Hide Administration block"></span>
</div>
<div class="desc" style="display:none;border: 1px solid #eee;padding: 6px 12px;color: #999;font-size: 13px;width:90%;float: left;">
  <p>Some Description</p>
</div>

<div id="shw_desc" style="background-color: #dfdfdf;font-size: 14px;float: left;padding: 4px 12px;width: 90.3%;color: #666;" class="nt_selected">
  <span>Description 2</span><span id="shw_desc_icon" style="float:right;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"><img class="block-hider-hide" alt="Hide Administration block" src="image" tabindex="0" title="Hide Administration block"></span>
</div>
<div class="desc" style="display:none;border: 1px solid #eee;padding: 6px 12px;color: #999;font-size: 13px;width:90%;float: left;">
  <p>Some Description 2</p>
</div>
```

Again, having said all that, try to get rid of the duplicate identifiers and use other common attributes of those elements to select them.
Of course, context awareness still applies just the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Or the idea**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var collapsed = "image";
    
      $(".meclick").click(function() {
        var $box = $(this).parents('.box:first');
          if(!$box.find('.desc:first').hasClass('visible'))
          {
            $box.find('.desc:first').addClass('visible');
            $box.find('.desc:first').slideDown();
            $box.find('.desc:first').find("#shw_desc_icon img:first").attr("src", collapsed).css("transform", "rotate(0deg)");
          }
          else
          {
           $box.find('.desc:first').removeClass('visible');
            $box.find('.desc:first').slideUp();
            $box.find('.desc:first').find("#shw_desc_icon img:first").attr("src", collapsed).css("transform", "rotate(180deg)");
          }
    
    
      });
    });
```

```css
.visible{}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    
    <div id="shw_desc" style="background-color: #dfdfdf;font-size: 14px;float: left;padding: 4px 12px;width: 90.3%;color: #666;" class="meclick nt_selected">
      <span>Description</span><span id="shw_desc_icon" style="float:right;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"><img class="block-hider-hide" alt="Hide Administration block" src="image" tabindex="0" title="Hide Administration block"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="desc" style="display:none;border: 1px solid #eee;padding: 6px 12px;color: #999;font-size: 13px;width:90%;float: left;">
      <p>Some Description</p>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="box">
    <div id="shw_desc" style="background-color: #dfdfdf;font-size: 14px;float: left;padding: 4px 12px;width: 90.3%;color: #666;" class="meclick nt_selected">
      <span>Description 2</span><span id="shw_desc_icon" style="float:right;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"><img class="block-hider-hide" alt="Hide Administration block" src="image" tabindex="0" title="Hide Administration block"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="desc" style="display:none;border: 1px solid #eee;padding: 6px 12px;color: #999;font-size: 13px;width:90%;float: left;">
      <p>Some Description 2</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```